# Как проверить в какие архитектуры нужно включить .so файлы?

Tags: android, gradle, native

Проблема вот в чем, я использую нативный код который компилируется и собирается для каждой архитектуры как копия, то есть есть у меня `my_native_lib.so` и я использую 4 архитектуры "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" значит в итоге my_native_lib который весит 10Мб скомпилируется для каждой и получить и итоге, что апк прибавит +40Мб (+-).

Теперь на моем примере, мое приложение использует opencv, .so которой весит ~63Мб то есть он будет скомпилирован для каждой архитектуры. Я добавил фильтр

```
       ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
```

и немного сьекономил места исключивши MIPS, но вопрос в том, как можно понять какие архитектуры можно еще исключить? Или вот эти 4 "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" это основные и никуда от них не деться?

P.S. вроде как opencv должен собираться только для `x86_64` , но судя по скриншоту он собирается для каждой (размер в каждой следующей меньше, но все равно)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно спокойно оставить только `armeabi-v7a` > 90% устройств и `x86` - несколько процентов

- `mips` - он удален из поддержки последних версий NDK
- `arm64-v8a` - 64-х разрядная архитектура ARM - обычный `armeabi-v7a` его поддерживает
- `x86_64` - не используется в Android устройствах (в районе 0%)

[Статистика за 2017 год](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808222202/http://hwstats.unity3d.com:80/mobile/cpu-android.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где можно найти эту инфу `armeabi-v7a > 90%` ?

Comment: [Есть статистика за 2017 год](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808222202/http://hwstats.unity3d.com:80/mobile/cpu-android.html), с тех пор картина вряд ли сильно поменялась

Comment: Добавил в тело ответа скриншот и ссылку

Comment: Только маркет требует в обязательном порядке включать в состав 64-битные библиотеки: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit. А размер конечного APK можно уменьшить, если публиковать в `bundle`. Естественно если речь идёт о публикации в гугло-магазине. Либо разбить на несколько APK под каждую архитектуру.